# Alternative SICStus Prolog FFI SP_define_c_predicate()

Tags: prolog, ffi, sicstus-prolog

I pasted the  SICStus Prolog 4.3.3
[`SP_define_c_predicate()`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/cpg_002dref_002dSP_005fdefine_005fc_005fpredicate.html)  sample as-is—and...  *failed*:

```
$ /usr/local/sicstus4.3.3/bin/splfr square.pl square.c
square.c: In function ‘square_it’:
square.c:7:3: error: unknown type name ‘SP_WORD’
   SP_WORD arg1;
   ^
square.c:13:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘sp_GlobalSICStus_square->dispatch_API_SICSTUS_H->pSP_get_integer’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   if (!SP_get_integer(tmp,&arg1))
   ^
square.c:13:3: note: expected ‘SP_integer *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
Uncaught exception from user code:
    ! Could not compile square.c
```

So far, I grepped the SICStus C include files for `SP_WORD`—to no avail.

Do you have some hints how I can make it work?  Thank you in advance!

(FYI: I'm using x86-64 Linux Mint 17 with gcc version 4.8.4.)

Comment: `find sicstus4.3.3 -name '*.c'|xargs grep -l SP_WORD`

Comment: @false. I'm not near my PC in a moment. What does that `find` find? (I only grepped in the include files...)

Comment: `sicstus-4.3.3/library/clpfd/arith.c` and many more in that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples should have used `SP_integer` instead of the internal type `SP_WORD`.